# libGDX make touchDown loop until touchUp

Tags: libgdx

I'm making game in libGDX.

I want to implement game controls, but I have problem with `touchDown` method. touchDown  method runs only once. I want to loop in touchDown  until touchUp is called. Can someone help me ?

```
class  onPlayerGoLeftListener extends InputListener {

    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //start runnable   (move player)     

        return true;
    }

    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //stop runnable
    }

}
```

Thanks

p.s. I don't like to use main update method to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't "loop" inside an event callback or render callback, as the whole system will stop.  One way to get what you want is to set a flag in the `touchDown` method, clear the flag in the `touchUp` method, and then put the "body" of your loop in `render`, guarded by your flag.

```
boolean touchActive = false;

public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
   //start runnable   (move player)     
   touchActive = true;
   return true;
}

public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
   //stop runnable
   touchActive = false;
}


public void render(float delta) {
   ...
   if (touchActive) {
      // Do one iteration of your "while" loop
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Would the enableRepeatableEvent(true) also be a solution? Or is this only for keyboard events? I am using the approach you wrote above, but i want to know if the other solution would work.

Answer (score 1):

In render() or in your draw thread you can just use

```
 if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){
  //some thing move()
}
```